# How can I separate multiple entries on a single get-context

Tags: powershell, token

I have a file with:

```
name user phone other
```

PowerShell script:

```
get-content -Path Z:\folder\name.txt |
ForEach-Object {
   (get-hotfix -Computername $_ | sort-object Installedon)[-1]
}
```

works great.

I would like to use a file with:

```
name user phone other
```

How do I isolate only the name from multiple items on the line?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the existing answers will work, however if you'd prefer to work with objects, try this:

```
Get-Content -Path Z:\folder\name.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " " | 
ForEach-Object {
 (get-hotfix -Computername $_.name | sort-object Installedon)[-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you script to something like that (use Split() to separate different words in the input string):

```
get-content -Path Z:\folder\name.txt |
ForEach-Object {
   $tokens = $($_.Split(" "));
   (get-hotfix -Computername $tokens[0] | sort-object Installedon)[-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use .split(), and take the first element:

```
$line = 'name user phone other'
$line.split()[0]

name
```